# get URL of parent page inside when inside an iframe

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

I have an iframe (iframe.php) inside my main page (index.php). I want to echo the URL of the main page inside the iframe. I know how to echo the URL of any page but not when it is inside an iframe. When i try this, it is echoing only the URL of the iframe and not of the main page. It sounds simple but not able to figure it out.

**REASON**: the reason why i chose php and why i am trying to do this is, i need to verify the URL from which this page is being accessed... do not want the iframe to be accessed unless the user is in index.php and reject the user from accessing it if he is not in the iframe of the main page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has no idea about an iframe, it's just served as another page and interpreted by the browser...

You could do something like...

```
<iframe src="frame.php?from=<?php echo currentPageURL() ?>">
```

Then inside the iframe, you can access `$_GET['from']`. Just make sure you verify, as that would be insecure.

Here is the code I typically use to return the current page URL:

```
function currentPageURL() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
    $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code, i had this idea but the problem was how would i validate the content in _GET['from']? I mean people can add junk script after frame.php and that might affect the website to any extent... apart from that, people could enter the currentPageURL() value directly into the browser and inside the iframe the $_GET value will read that it is correct and allow the user.

Comment: Well that's just it... any method you attempt to do this will be vulnerable. Javascript is client side, so it's ridiculously easy to spoof. With this method you would have to have a whitelist of some sort of what is allowed to be there. That would be the only way to make it secure.

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

to read the parent.

It work for me.

The javascript code can't talk easily with PHP
The ?from=

Comment: Note that `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` is not secure as it is set be the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert(top.location.href);</script>
```

I think it should work. :-)

Comment: There is javascript in keywords so I wrote javascript code. :-)